# Parse output of df --output to select first % sign

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, subprocess

I have a `subprocess` command im running:
`import subprocess; subprocess.call(['df', '--output=pcent'])`

which `output`s:

```
Use%
 80%
  0%
  0%
  3%
  1%
  0%
 51%
  0%
```

I want to grab the second `%` with a number next to it (`80%` in this case, and perform a calculation on it).

How can I easily do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `subprocess.call` only returns the return code, so you need some other `subprocess` function, like `check_output`:

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['df', '--output=pcent'])
```

Then, the output is provided as `bytes` (python 3). So you have to decode it as ASCII, then I would use nested list & generator comprehensions to:

- split according to blanks (newlines/spaces)
- processing each token and removing the percent sign
- only converting to integer if the token is composed of digits

code (with mockup output of your command so everyone can reproduce):

```
output = b"""Use%
 80%
  0%
  0%
  3%
  1%
  0%
 51%
  0%"""

percents = [int(x) for x in (y.rstrip("%") for y in output.decode("ascii").split()) if x.isdigit()]

print(percents)
```

which gives:

```
[80, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 51, 0]
```

that's more than you're asking of course. To take the first item just take first item of this list or take the first token with a generator comprehension and `next`:

```
first_percent = next(int(x) for x in (y.rstrip("%") for y in output.decode("ascii").split()) if x.isdigit())
```